# ADAL Proxy Error while connecting through Rake Task

Tags: proxy, ruby-on-rails-5, azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am following [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ruby) website for connecting to Microsoft Graph to get the access token using ADAL gem.
I have written a Rake task to perform this. This works fine in the open network but fails in the Corporate Network.

I have set the proxy credentials in the bash profile and in the bashrc file in my terminal

```
export http_proxy=http://username:pwd@proxy.corporate.com:8080/
export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:pwd@proxy.corporate.com:8080/
export https_proxy=http://username:pwd@proxy.corporate.com:8080/
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:pwd@proxy.corporate.com:8080/
```

I am receiving

> SocketError: Failed to open TCP connection to login.microsoftonline.com:443 (Hostname not known: login.microsoftonline.com)

Comment: Seems like you should update your `/etc/hosts` file as well. Another problem could be related with the DNS of on your local machine - some VPN apps are changing it.

Comment: I am using the Gem ADAL as mentioned in the above URL, Is it because of the gem it is blocking via proxy?

Comment: @radoAngelov - Is that possible to et proxy for ADAL gem

Comment: I cannot answer you. ADAL is used to work with Azure, I have never used it professionally :(

Comment: @radoAngelov - Now the issue has been resolved after I modify the changes in the gem

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Issue has been resolved after tweeking the user_credential.rb file in ADAL gem

File to edit: /azure-activedirectory-library-for-ruby-24e1b7f0dc37/lib/adal/user_credential.rb

```
def realm_discovery_response
  @realm_discovery_response ||=
    JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get(realm_discovery_uri))
end
```

Replace the above code with the below as **Net::HTTP.get** doesnot take the system proxy use and only **Net::HTTP.Get.new** works

```
    def realm_discovery_response
      uri = URI.parse(realm_discovery_uri.to_s)
      puts "URI #{uri}"
      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      http.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'
      req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
      res = http.request(req)
      @realm_discovery_response ||= JSON.parse(res.body)
    end
```